# Webpage in iPhone showing nothing

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

Here's the URL:

http://www.ourpagesonline.co.uk/mobile/index.asp?ID=207&aID=1

It works fine in iPhone simulator, all my desktop browsers, but in the iPhone all it shows is the GUI but no images...

Any know what's going on here?  Is it just too complicated for iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll hit you with the classic "works for me".

[image]

So the problem is definitely not the iPhone (at least not the iPhone 4), although the usability kind of sucks.

Answer (score 1):

it works on my iPod touch 2nd generation if i browse to the page in safari...

there's something strange with zoom... but all is loaded, also images

Comment: @Tom: You're welcome... ps. I started iPhopne web using templates from this: http://snippetspace.com/projects/iwebkit/ ... it's nice and easy to adapt, it may help you...